# Button is growing on jquery mobile's 'vmousedown'

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm working on a mobile game using phonegap. I have two buttons (left and right) to control an avatar. 
On startup the buttons are sized well. But on first click on one of the buttons, both grow a little.
This happend on a Sony Xperia Z1 (Android 4.3) - so I tested it on an older Samsung Galaxy SII (Android 4.0.4), too. Here I do not have this issue.
So I think it is something like an highlight function?

My html:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="gameScreen">
    </canvas>
    <img id="buttonleft" src="sources/button_left.png">
    <img id="buttonright" src="sources/button_right.png">
    <script src="js/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

My javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //set canvas width to screen width
    canvas.width = $(window).width();
    canvas.height = $(window).height();
    //calc parameters according to device size
    var buttonWidth = canvas.width/6.5;
    var buttonMargin = canvas.width/20.0;
    $('#buttonright').css('width', buttonWidth+'px');
    $('#buttonleft').css('width', buttonWidth+'px');
    $('#buttonright').css('bottom', buttonMargin+'px');
    $('#buttonleft').css('bottom', buttonMargin+'px');
    $('#buttonright').css('right', buttonMargin+'px');
    $('#buttonleft').css('left', buttonMargin+'px');
    character.src = 'sources/rooney_large.png';

   //initialize the game
   init();

   //player's controll
   $("#buttonleft").on('vmousedown', function(){
       moveLeft = true;
   });
   $("#buttonright").on('vmousedown', function(){
       moveRight = true;
   });
   $(document).on('vmouseup', function(){
       moveLeft = false;
   moveRight = false;
   }); 
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: try any device specific styles?

Comment: also, can you show a jsfiddle or any live demo for further debug

Comment: I tried device specific styles first. I thought the issue comes from the css, so I tried to calculate the size of the buttons via javascript...